# ExpressJS static dynamically

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to serve `/mbti/:lang/` with static files from directory `./mbti/:lang/`.

That is:

```
/mbti/en/ -> ./mbti/en/index.html
/mbti/en/some.json -> ./mbti/en/some.json
```

I found static, but seems like it can't do this:

```
app.use('/mbti/:lang/', express.static(__dirname + '/mbti/' + :lang));
```

How can I implement this? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do that, just make /mbti/ a static route and anything below that root will be served as static

```
express.static(__dirname + '/mbti');
```

Comment: thanks, works with `app.use('/mbti/', express.static(__dirname + '/mbti'));`